# Reflection: FindMembers returning empty

Tags: c#, reflection, types, attributes, memberinfo

I'm trying to list all members with a given attribute, I've implemented a method that uses FindMembers but it always return an empty collection. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public List<MemberInfo> GetMembers<TClass, TAttribute>()
{
    Type type = typeof(TClass);
    Type attributeType = typeof(TAttribute);
    List<MemberInfo> members = type.FindMembers(MemberTypes.All, BindingFlags.Default, Filter, null).ToList();
    return members;
}

public bool Filter(MemberInfo memberInfo, object filterCriteria)
{
    return memberInfo.IsDefined(typeof(TestAttribute));
}

[Test]
public string MethodName()
{
    return "test";
}
```

When it I call like this:

```
List<MemberInfo> members = GetMembers<TestClass, TestAttribute>();
```

It returns empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=netframework-4.7.2#fields), `BindingFlags.Default`:

> Specifies that no binding flags are defined.

You need to tell `FindMembers` exactly what you want, for example if you want public members that are either static or instance members:

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance;
List<MemberInfo> members = type.FindMembers(MemberTypes.All, flags, Filter, null).ToList();
```

As an aside, you may want to add a generic type constraint to your `GetMember` function to restrict the attribute type:

```
public List<MemberInfo> GetMember<TClass, TAttribute>() 
    where TAttribute : Attribute
```

Comment: And if I want any kind of members? Is there an umbrella flag?

Comment: The only flag that's really missing from the list I show is `BindingFlags.NonPublic` which will also return private members. What else do you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `GetMembers()` method and then filter your result:

```
var members = type.GetMembers().Where(x => Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(TestAttribute))).ToList()
```

Comment: Thats a good alternative but I think its more elegant done the full reflection way. Thanks.